# How to let XGBoost output as int, not objects?

Tags: text-mining, xgboost

I am using XGBoost to classify fake or true news. However after dealing with the text by Tfidf vector, training my XGBclassifier and running the predict X_test successfully.

The error message displaying when calculating accuracy,precision,Recall and F-measure. Message is:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

[image]